# How to test for specific warning(s), as produced by "warnings()"?

Tags: r, tidyverse, testthat

**The problem**

I'm using the `read_delim` function to read in a lot of csv files (non-comma delimited). This produces warnings because some of the columns have the same name. I don't want to edit the original files, and I cannot change the column names while I read them in with `read_delim`. So these warnings are unavoidable. However I would like to do a test that these are the only warnings that are generated, and that there are no other warnings such as wrong column specifications, etc.

**What I can think of myself**

I can capture the warnings with `myWarnings <- warnings()` after running the code but I'm not sure how to test anything with this. The problem is that `myWarnings` is a list of class `warnings` that I'm not sure how to test against. For example `myWarnings[[1]]` produces `NULL`, so I cannot test element per element. It's also not a character vector but a list.

The usual way to do this is to capture the warnings while the function is running. For example `testthat::expect_warning(read_delim(...))`, but in order to do this I would have to run my code twice: once for the result, and once for testing. I don't want to do this as it takes too much time (and isn't a very clean way to do things).

**The code**

```
# Pseudocode because you don't have my input files anyway
library(tidyverse)
myInputs <- list.files("myFolder", pattern = ".csv$")
myColTypes <- cols(col1 = col_character(), col2 = col_logical(), etc.)
myData <- map(myInputs, read_delim, delim = "|", col_types = myColTypes)
```

Afterwards R tells me in the console: `There were 36 warnings (use warnings() to see them)`. Each of these warnings reads: `Duplicated column names deduplicated: 'col' => 'col_1' [32], 'col' => 'col_2' [54], 'col' => 'col_3' [211]`.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
# Again pseudocode, because this is what I would like but it doesn't work.
myWarnings <- warnings()
testthat::expect_equal(
    myWarnings,
    warning("Duplicated column names deduplicated: 'col' => 'col_1' [32], 'col' => 'col_2' [54], 'col' => 'col_3' [211]"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `testthat::expect_named()`. Why? The list you get from `warnings()` is a named list, where the names are the warning messages. Let's look at an example:

```
for ( i in 1:10 ) {
    x <- log(-i)
}
# Warning messages:
# 1: In log(-i) : NaNs produced
# ...
# 10: In log(-i) : NaNs produced
w <- warnings()
str(w)
# List of 10
#  $ NaNs produced: language log(-i)
#  ...
#  $ NaNs produced: language log(-i)
#  - attr(*, "dots")= list()
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "warnings"
names(w)
# [1] "NaNs produced" "NaNs produced" "NaNs produced" "NaNs produced"
# [5] "NaNs produced" "NaNs produced" "NaNs produced" "NaNs produced"
# [9] "NaNs produced" "NaNs produced"
```

Then we can use `testthat::expect_named()` to test equality for the warning messages:

```
testthat::expect_named(w, rep("NaNs produced", 10))
```